# json_normalize to transform several nested lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dictionary where one of the elements is a list of several lists. I am trying to use `json_normalize` to transform some elements in pandas dataframe.

Reproducible dict

```
my_dict = {'policyId':['123'],
           'Elements':[[{'id': '100',
                        'coverages': [{'id': 'ABC',
                                         'premiums': {'var1': {},
                                         'var2': {}},
                                         'quoteDetails': [{'id': 'PRICE',
                                                              'tags': ['SOMETHING'],
                                                              'value': 150.0,
                                                              'modifiable': False},
                                                             {'id': 'DISCOUNT',
                                                              'tags': ['SOMETHING'],
                                                              'value': 10.0,
                                                              'modifiable': False}]}],
                                                          'mandatory': True,
                                                          'selected': True},
                       {'id': '101',
                        'coverages': [{'id': 'DEF',
                                         'premiums': {'var1': {},
                                         'var2': {}},
                                         'quoteDetails': [{'id': 'PRICE',
                                                              'tags': ['SOMETHING'],
                                                              'value': 200.0,
                                                              'modifiable': False},
                                                             {'id': 'DISCOUNT',
                                                              'tags': ['SOMETHING'],
                                                              'value': 15.0,
                                                              'modifiable': False}]}],
                                                          'mandatory': True,
                                                          'selected': True}
                      ]]
          }
```

I already tried using `json_normalize` in several ways but I still cannot get the expect result.

This is my desired result

```
policyId coverages  PRICE   DISCOUNT
123      ABC        150.0   10.0
123      DEF        200.0   15.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON format is too flexible for `json_normalize` to cover all use cases. You can use the good old Python list compresension:

```py
value_for_id = lambda id_, lst: next((i.get("value") for i in lst if i.get("id") == id_))
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "policyId": my_dict["policyId"][0],
            "coverage": coverage["id"],
            "PRICE": value_for_id("PRICE", coverage["quoteDetails"]),
            "DISCOUNT": value_for_id("DISCOUNT", coverage["quoteDetails"]),
        }
        for element in my_dict["Elements"][0]  # this double-nested list look like a mistake
        for coverage in element["coverages"]
    ]
)
```